# SQL Server ReplMerge Process could not connect to Subscriber

Tags: sql-server, merge, replication, subscription, sql-server-2019

I've setup the following situation:

Server has a SQL Server 2019 Standard edition and is the **Publisher**.
Local laptop has a SQL Server 2019 Express edition and is the **Subscriber**.

Server and laptop are connected via VPN.

I created a publication on the server and a subscription on the local laptop.
So far so good.

The synchronisation is setup as a **Merge Sync**.
The subscription method is **Pull**.

I've created a **batch file** in orde to start the synchronisation on my local laptop.

It contains the following code:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\COM\replmerg.exe" -Publisher Publication-Server\TEST -PublisherDB TEST -Publication TESTPub -Subscriber Subscription-Local\TEST -SubscriberDB TEST-SubscriptionType 1 -SubscriberSecurityMode 1 -Distributor Publication-Server\TEST -OutputVerboseLevel 2 -Validate 3  -Continuous

Whenever I execute the batch file, it starts and directly stops with the following:
**Message: The process could not connect to Subscriber 'Subscription-Local\TEST'.
Number: 20084.**
Then it follows by disconnecting from OLE DB Subscriber 'Subscription-Local\TEST'.

I'm running the batch file with a Windows user that has **db_owner permissions** on the **Subscription database** TEST.

I'm lost about what to do, to get the batch file to work properly.

If you need more information, shoot!

So I tried changing from Windows Authentication to SQL Server Authentication.
Same issue.

I tried running the batch file as Administrator.
Same issue.

I tried deleting the Publication and Subscription and recreate them.
Same issue.

Comment: Can you connect to the subscriber with SSMS?

Comment: From my local laptop I can.